# Understanding a complex SQL code with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a lengthy query which I am trying to understand. I learned in this forum that the best way to understand complex queries is to split them, check their results separately and then combine. I am pasting a part of code here.

> Please help me understand why its giving me an error: *Unable to parse query text*. *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.*

```
(SELECT        AppID, AppDetailID, AppDetailSavePointID, FieldID, Value AS Acct_Renewed
 FROM          v_RptAppDetailField_v001
 WHERE         (FieldID IN (- 87, - 88, - 152, - 179, - 258, - 263)) 
               AND (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (Value IS NOT NULL)) AS Acct_Renewed 
 ON 
               v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001.AppDetailID = Acct_Renewed.AppDetailID AND 
               v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001.AppID = Acct_Renewed.AppID
```

When I deleted this part of code from the above code. I got the results. Please help me understand the ON clause here. I am confused as it doesn't mention any join as well. Also please be aware that there was a left outer join right after this code.

```
AS Acct_Renewed 
 ON 
               v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001.AppDetailID = Acct_Renewed.AppDetailID AND 
               v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001.AppID = Acct_Renewed.AppID
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The as is simply an alias.  I think the `ON` clause is what is actually causing the error.  The on clause would be needed to join the subquery (the select inside the parens) to another table or query.

Comment: I really fail to understand why downvote for my queston. Initially when I was new to this website, I agree I made some formatting mistakes and some vagues questions were asked. But now before posting a question, I do my research well, after failig to get an answers, I post my question here and still get a downvote...Are newcomers restricted to this forum? The one who gave a downvote, please explain why? It will help me ask better questions in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first block of SQL isn't a complete query.  The part you delete is the extra piece that is part of the larger query.

What's happening is that this sql...

```
SELECT        AppID, AppDetailID, AppDetailSavePointID, FieldID, Value AS Acct_Renewed
 FROM          v_RptAppDetailField_v001
 WHERE         (FieldID IN (- 87, - 88, - 152, - 179, - 258, - 263)) 
               AND (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (Value IS NOT NULL)
```

...is being used as a subquery.  You can get more details here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

As a subquery, it is used just like a table.  That's why it has `AS Acct_Renewed` followed by an `ON` clause.  This subquery is being joined to the previous table that you didn't copy using that `ON` clause.

Comment: Thank you! I got a better idea of the subquery through the link you provided. Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 1):

The following part of the query, which gives you results, independently is called an **inline view**. You can give a name (alias) for inline views. Here, it is given the name **Acct_Renewed**.

```
(SELECT        AppID, AppDetailID, AppDetailSavePointID, FieldID, Value AS Acct_Renewed
 FROM          v_RptAppDetailField_v001
 WHERE         (FieldID IN (- 87, - 88, - 152, - 179, - 258, - 263)) 
               AND (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (Value IS NOT NULL)
```

The following conditions indicate that the inline view is joined with another table / view / inline view named as **v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001**.

```
ON 
               v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001.AppDetailID = Acct_Renewed.AppDetailID AND 
               v_RptFlatAppDetail_v001.AppID = Acct_Renewed.AppID
```

**References**:

1. [Inline views (Oracle) on MacLochlainns Weblog](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/tag/inline-views/)
2. [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins on Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thank you @Joseph. I really liked your explanation and the references link you provided. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select AppID,
AppDetailID, 
AppDetailSavePointID, 
FieldID, 
Value AS Acct_Renew  
(SELECT        
AppID, 
AppDetailID, 
AppDetailSavePointID, 
FieldID, 
Value AS Acct_Renewed
 FROM          v_RptAppDetailField_v001 V
 WHERE         (V.FieldID IN (- 87, - 88, - 152, - 179, - 258, - 263)) 
               AND (VAppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (V.Value IS NOT NULL )
               FROM v_RptAppDetailField_v001 VV 
               INNER JOIN v_RptAppDetailField_v001 V
               ON  
               v.AppDetailID = vv.AppDetailID AND 
               v.AppID = vv.AppID
```